# Change boolean with if / else statement in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to change the value on a boolean based on the size of the window but am having trouble with the syntax.

Here is what I've got:

```
    export class AppComponent {

      isSmall = true;

      constructor(){
        let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

        if (windowWidth <= 700) {
            isSmall = true;
        }
        else {
           isSmall = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is this "trouble"? Is an error reported?

Comment: Also note that a `<=` comparison has as its value a boolean, so you can simply write `isSmall = windowWidth <= 700;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent {

isSmall:boolean = true;
windowWidth: number;

constructor(){
    this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth <= 700) {
       this.isSmall = true;
    }
    else {
       this.isSmall = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take windows width in angular below code will help..

```
  angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    alert($window.innerWidth);
   });
```

now using $window.innerWidth you can set your variable

Answer (score 0):

To get the value updated on window resize, you can use

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize() {
    this.isSmall = windowWidth <= 700;
}
```